# Dell Inspiron 5570 Fingerprint Sensor Driver

Tags: 18.04, dell, fingerprint-reader

I have a Dell Inspiron 5570 laptop with dualboot of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Fingerprint sensor works well on Windows, but doesn't find any driver for Ubuntu.
Does anybody found a solution for this frustrating situation?

My lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 27c6:5301  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 
Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0737 Microsoft Corp. Compact Optical Mouse 500
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please, post `lsusb` (or whatelse) output of that piece of hardware. Maybe it is not only present in your Dell model, thus it will be easier get help...

Answer (score 0):

The reader is https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/27c6:5301 and according to these discussions it doesn't have a way to make it work yet:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234844

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues/161